# how to write the sqlite command to choose different records?

Tags: sqlite

There are two tables(t1 and t2) in my database,both of them has three fields `code` ,`date` and `price`.t1 has 800 records ,t2 has 790 records , `code` fields  are the same.
select distinct code from t1  =  select distinct code from t2

i want to choose records from t1 and t2.

suppose that in t1

```
code  date
x1    d1
x1    d2
x1    d3
```

in t2:

```
code  date
x1    d4
x1    d2
x1    d5
```

I want to choose records in t1.

```
code  date
x1    d1
x1    d3
```

I want to choose  records in t2.

```
code  date
x1    d4
x1    d5
```

how to write the sqlite  command?

Think for CL,it works fine for me,
but it is difficult for me to understand the query.

1.what is the meaning of

```
SELECT 1
FROM t2
 WHERE t2.code = t1.code
     AND t2.date = t1.date  ?
```

Why don't write it as

```
SELECT 1
FROM t1
 WHERE t2.code = t1.code
     AND t2.date = t1.date  ?
```

2.why i can't write it as

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t2,t1
              WHERE t2.code = t1.code
                AND t2.date = t1.date)
```

the query SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.code = t1.code AND t2.date = t1.date will get two 1 .and what is the meaning of two 1 exists?

Comment: You need to INNER JOIN the tables and add a condition `WHERE code = 'x1' AND date != 'd2'` - JOIN [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a record exists, use EXISTS with a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).
This selects all `t1` rows whose combination of `code`/`date` values do not exist in `t2`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t2
                  WHERE t2.code = t1.code
                    AND t2.date = t1.date)
```

Comment: how can i make the selected table as my new t1 table?

Comment: You mean, you want to delete all other records? Do you want to do the same with `t2`?

Comment: it works fine for me,but it is difficult for me to understand the query.

Comment: the query `SELECT 1  FROM t2  WHERE t2.code = t1.code AND t2.date = t1.date` will get  two 1 .and what is the meaning of two 1 exists?

Comment: The subquery is *correlated*, i.e., it will get different results for each row in `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT *
   FROM t1
   WHERE (t1_code || t1_date) not in
         (
            select (t2_code || t2_date)
          from t2 );
```

What I am doing is just concatenating code and date in t1 and concatenating code and date in t2 and getting the combinations that are there in t1 and not there in t2.